# Open a dialog on down of drop down icon

Tags: java, android, menu, dialog

i have a drop down icon on my screen. If i click the drop down icon i want to show a dialog or popup menu on the bottom of the icon. Successfully I opened the dialog on menu click but that arrow doesn't fit to the icon.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links:

1. [Super Tool Tips](https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips)
2. [Quick Action Dialog](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)
3. [Code Project - Quick Action](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521455/Quick-action-pattern-in-Android-and-simple-impleme)
4. [Help Pop Ups](http://shardulprabhu.blogspot.in/2012/08/blog-post_29.html)

It will be helpful for you to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method in your Icon's click event:

```
public void showPopupMenu(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
    }
```